# append multiple columns to df while keeping other column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with multiple authors associated with one title and location:

```
title | location | author 1 | author 2 | author 3
---------------------------------------------------
A     |  US      |  jon smit| johnny   | brad
B     |  Asia    | Kenny lee| None     | None
C     |  Europe  | gutentag | bonjour  | None
```

And I want output to ignore any None values and look like:

```
title | location | author   | 
-----------------------------
A     |  US      |  jon smit|
A     |  US      | johnny   | 
A     |  US      | brad     |
B     |  Asia    | Kenny lee| 
C     |  Europe  | gutentag | 
C     |  Europe  | bonjour  |
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Like `df = df.set_index(['title','location']).stack().reset_index(level=2, drop=True).reset_index(name='author')`

Comment: @jezrael Also need to drop `None` values. For this reason only I answered the question.

Comment: @MayankPorwal - I think `None` is `Nonetype`, stack remove them, so not, no necessary..

Comment: Ok I thought `stack` only removes `NaN` values.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the info @jezrael.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`df.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) with [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) to replace `None` values to `NaN` and [`df.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) to drop `NaN`.

Lastly, use [`df.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) at last to sort the rows on column `title`:

```
In [1414]: import numpy as np

In [1415]: x = df.melt(id_vars=['title', 'location'],  value_name='author')[['title', 'location', 'author']].replace('None', np.nan).dropna().sort_values('title')

In [1416]: x
Out[1416]: 
  title location     author
0     A       US   jon smit
3     A       US     johnny
6     A       US       brad
1     B     Asia  Kenny lee
2     C   Europe   gutentag
5     C   Europe    bonjour
```

**OR:** If your `None` values are `Nonetype` and not `strings`, you don't need `replace`.

```
x = d.melt(id_vars=["title", "location"], value_name="author")[
    ["title", "location", "author"]
].dropna()
```